# Task.Start fails when continuation actions are not inline

Tags: c#, .net

What is the wrong the with following code?
Task.Start fails with index out of range exception. To be more clear.. it is failing because the i value is coming as 3 in the for loop !!!

```
ActionProvider m1 = new ActionProvider();
ActionProvider m2 = new ActionProvider();
ActionProvider m3 = new ActionProvider();

List<Action> actions = new List<Action>() 
{
    ()=> { m2.DoIt(); }, 
    ()=> { m3.DoIt(); }, 
};

Task t = new Task(() => { m1.DoIt(); });

for (int i = 0; i < actions.Count; i++)
{
    t.ContinueWith(t1 => actions[i]());
}

t.Start();
```

Answer (score 2):

It is probably because you reuse the same variable, i, several times. So when you execute the task i has been incremented.

Try to change your for-loop as follows:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < actions.Count; i++)
    {
        var action = actions[i];
        t.ContinueWith(t1 => action());
    }
```

The only difference here is that I create a copy of the variable that I pass to ContinueWith.

Comment: Exactly - for more information, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: If i modify the code to use for each, interestingly this executes the code three times foreach (var item in actions)
            {
                t.ContinueWith(t1 => item());
            }

Comment: @user730702: That is as expected. With the foreach the item variable will be updated each time, just as if you do what I suggested in my answer. In your first case you reference the variable i inside the delegate you call from ContinueWith. That delegate is then called at a later time after i has changed it's value.